# creating a binary operator function within a package

Tags: r

i'm trying to add a binary operator function to a package of mine, but it is not loading with the package. for example, i define this function and save it as a file named 'wo.R'

```
`%wo%` <- function(x, y) {
    x[!x %in% y]
}
```

and create the documentation file 'wo.Rd'

```
\name{\%wo\%}
\alias{\%wo\%}
\title{Without}
\description{Elements in one vector without matching elements in a second vector.}
\usage{x \%wo\% y}
\arguments{
  \item{x}{A vector.}
  \item{y}{A vector.}
}
\value{A vector.}
\author{me, based on example in the \code{\link{match}} function documentation.}
\examples{
(1:10) \%wo\% c(3,7,12)
}
```

when i run `R CMD check myPackage` it gives this error when checking the documentation example: `Error: could not find function "%wo%" Execution halted`. i can remove the example, and install my package successfully, but the %wo% function isn't loading with my package. i can source the 'wo.R' file in an R session and it works. i can also define the function as `wo <- function(x, y) x[!x %in% y]` and that seems to work fine. i poked around the source code for other packages, such as 'operators', and my source and documentation files seem consistent with them, but i'm obviously overlooking something.

Comment: Are you exporting the function? If so, how? If you are using a regular expression to export, perhaps that needs updating, or else simply export this particular function.

Comment: @Andrie- aha! that was the problem. i just had the predefined `exportPattern("^[[:alpha:]]+")` in the NAMESPACE file. adding `export("%wo%")` did the trick. thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to export the function in your NAMESPACE.

Add an `export` statement to your documentation file:

```
export("%wo%")
```

Comment: I have added `export("%liken%")` to the file named `NAMESSPACE`. It solved my issue. Thanks.