# R package documentation: "Undocumented arguments in documentation object" for a function with no arguments

Tags: r, r-package, roxygen2

I receive the following warning when trying to check my package: `Undocumented arguments in documentation object '%ni%' '...' 'NA'`. The function (is it even a function? or is it just an operator?) doesn't take any arguments, but it appears that R is somehow identifying arguments (`...` and `NA`) that are not documented.

Here is the document that I use with `roxygen2` to create the package documentation:

```
#' @title
#' NOTIN Operator.
#'
#' @description
#' NOTIN operator.
#'
#' @details
#' Determine whether values in one vector are not in another vector.
#'
#' @return Vector of \code{TRUE} and \code{FALSE}, indicating whether values in
#' one vector are not in another vector.
#'
#' @family operators
#'
#' @export
#'
#' @examples
#' # Prepare Data
#' v1 <- c("Sally","Tom","Barry","Alice")
#' listToCheckAgainst <- c("Tom","Alice")
#'
#' v1 %ni% listToCheckAgainst
#' v1[v1 %ni% listToCheckAgainst]
#'
#' @seealso
#' \url{https://www.r-bloggers.com/2018/07/the-notin-operator/}

`%ni%` <- Negate(`%in%`)
```

Here is the relevant output I receive when checking the package:

```
W  checking for code/documentation mismatches (1.9s)
   Codoc mismatches from documentation object '%ni%':
   %ni%
     Code: function(...)
     Docs: function(..., NA)
     Argument names in docs not in code:
       NA
   
W  checking Rd \usage sections (3.7s)
   Undocumented arguments in documentation object '%ni%'
     '...' 'NA'
   
   Functions with \usage entries need to have the appropriate \alias
   entries, and all their arguments documented.
   The \usage entries must correspond to syntactically valid R code.
   See chapter 'Writing R documentation files' in the 'Writing R
   Extensions' manual.
```

How can I get rid of the warning?

Comment: Your function takes the same arguments as `%in%` and just negates the results. All operators in R are still functions. You can bring up the documentation for + with `?"+"` so you still need to document the parameters. See the `?"%in%"` help page for examples. I guess the problem is that the `Negate` wrapper changes the function signature. It might be best not to use that when developing a package.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9225382/creating-a-binary-operator-function-within-a-package

Comment: I already exported the function to the `NAMESPACE`: `export("%ni%")` (as suggested in the link), so that's not the issue. It's helpful to know that the operator is a function, though it is weird that the arguments appear to differ from the `%in%` function. It'd be nice to be able to include it in the package because the function saves me tons of time in coding.

Comment: It would be better to define your function like `\`%ni%\` <- function(x, table) {!(x %in% table)}` so you can properly document the `x` and `table` arguments.

Comment: @MrFlick Your answer solved my problem. Thank you! I'd be happy to accept it as the answer if you'd like to post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can see the arguments to `%in%` and your `%ni%` operator using

```r
args(`%in%`)
#> function (x, table) 
#> NULL
`%ni%` <- Negate(`%in%`)
args(`%ni%`)
#> function (...) 
#> NULL
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1.9000)</sup>

So it looks like `Negate()` replaced the `%in%` arguments with `...`, and Roxygen messed up the help page generation. I think you will need to write the Rd file manually, or use an explicit definition of `%ni%`, or do something else to tell Roxygen how to get the usage right.

EDITED to add:

Another choice is to use a better `Negate` function that keeps the arguments, for example

```r
Negate2 <- function (f) 
{
    f <- match.fun(f)
    args <- names(formals(f))
    result <- function() !do.call(f, sapply(args, as.name))
    formals(result) <- formals(f)
    result
}

`%ni%` <- Negate2(`%in%`)
args(`%ni%`)
#> function (x, table) 
#> NULL
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1.9000)</sup>

This would require you to document the `x` and `table` arguments, but shouldn't cause problems in Roxygen.  I think it should evaluate properly, but I haven't done much testing.